# JS Functions & IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

When I run the following piece of JS code:

```
var x = (function () {
    console.log('Hello x!');
});

var y = function () {
    console.log('Hello y!');
};

var z = (function () {
    console.log('Hello z!')
    return 2;
})();

x();

y();
```

The following output is printed on the browser's console:

Hello z!

Hello x!

Hello y!

Why "**Hello z!**" is printed before "**Hello x**!" & "**Hello y!**". And how does the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) interact with the 'z' variable?

P.S. : I am a beginner.

Comment: The word "immediately" means "now" or "right away".  By adding the `()` to the end of the function expression, the function is immediately *called* (invoked) and the return value is the value of `z`.

Comment: The IIFE is immediatly invoked (called/run/etc). Before both X and Y.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Because this is IIFE:

```
var z = (function () {
    console.log('Hello z!')
    return 2;
})();
```

Without IIFE above code could be rewritten as:

```
var x = (function () {
    console.log('Hello x!');
});

var y = function () {
    console.log('Hello y!');
};

var z = function () {
    console.log('Hello z!')
    return 2;
};
z();

x();

y();
```

That's why 'Hello z' is printed first

Comment: OP knows that this is a IIFE (_"And how does the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) interact with the 'z' variable?"_)

Comment: "could be rewritten" yes and no. In this example `z` is a function. In the original `z` is `2`.

Comment: `var z = (function() { return 2; })()` is not the same as `var z = function() { ... }; z();`

Comment: @evolutionxbox @Andreas better luck rewriting above code so it stays the same (oops!) to illustrate why `Why "Hello z!" is printed first.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer it's how the your code is written, the call stack is calling the IIFE first, then the x function, then the y function. If you want a good visual representation, check out Loupe by Philip Roberts(http://latentflip.com/loupe/). It lets you write code and step through how it's called and executed. Helped me a lot when trying to understand execution sequence.

Comment: Which answer do you mean? On my screen your answer is top.

Comment: Sorry should have just referenced the answer. The answer from @bapafes482.

Answer (score 0):

The first I in IIFE means Immediately.
That's why this function is executed first.

In addition, the IIFE can not interact with the 'z' variable.
But you can pass arguments to it like this :

```
var hi = 'Hello z!';

var z = (function (txt) {
    console.log(txt)
})(hi);
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

The first two vars, `x` and `y` are assigned function values, while the third is assigned the value returned by the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE):

```
(function () { console.log('Hello z!'); return 2; }) // <= this is an expression
```

The enclosing parens `( ... )` make the function declaration an expression whose result is a function, and that function is immediately invoked by adding `()`. The invoked function returns `2` which is assigned to `z`, and the console output is a side-effect of the function executing.

Your code then goes on to invoke `x();` and `y()`, which log their strings to the console *after* `z()` was invoked while initializing `z`.

The IIFE *can* interact with `z`, but the value of `z` will always be `undefined` in this function, though not with any meaningful effect, because while it is executing `z` has been declared, but not yet assigned a value. It is assigned after the IIFE completes, with the return value of the function, `2`.